# Is it possible to make tensorflow graph summary?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm aware of Tensorboard and how awesome it is, but I think that simple console output with current graph summary is better (and faster) for prototyping purpose.
And also know that I can generate tensorboard graph after simply running session with last network node as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391075/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-without-a-training-op).

What I'm looking for is something similar to `model.summary()` from Keras.

In another words: how to iterate over tensorflow graph and print out only custom high end layer with their shapes and dtypes in the same order how all these layer where generated?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs

Comment: it's easily possible to extract the summary in dict format https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128858/10375049

Comment: Use can `tf.summary.graph`. For more details refer https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/graph

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. If you are using `tf.keras` wrapper to build you can easily visualize the graph, even before `model.compile()` method executes.
It's `keras` built-in functionality called [`plot_model()`](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/). 
*This method have dependency on `graphviz` and `pydot` libraries. 
for pydot installation : `pip install pydot` 
but for `graphviz` installation you have follow step in [this page](https://www.graphviz.org/download/). And also probably you have to restart the machine because of there it create *system environment variables*.
for tutorial on how to use this method follow [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/)

Answer (score 2):

To plot your model with shapes and dtypes before training you could use:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True, show_dtype=True)
```

where "model" is your built model. The output of a model could looks like this: [image]