# View architechure of my neural net before attempting to train it

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I which to play around with different architectures of neural networks made using TensorFlow 2. I.e. different numbers of layers, different layer types, different numbers of nodes in each layer etc etc. I am building my models with functions like `tf.keras.layers.Input()`, `tf.keras.layers.Dense()` and `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` etc. I also wish to visualise the models I have built as a sanity check. Looking at the documentation of TensorBoard it appears that to view your model you need to employ callbacks in your training process (model.fit). This seems rather clumsy - surely there must be a way to visualise your network before attempting to start training it. Apart from anything, the training may crash precisely because your model architecture is flawed somehow! If this visualisation could be done via something other than TensorBoard that would be fine too.

**EDIT:** It has been suggested that there may be an answer already => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391075/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-without-a-training-op) but it appears to involve the use of a session which I thought was no longer part of TensorFlow since version 2.

**EDIT:** I just found the `summary()` function. That tells me really quite a lot about my network before attempting to train it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to visualize a tensorflow graph without a training op?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391075/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-without-a-training-op)

Comment: @Edoardo Guerriero: I get... AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session' - I thought the whole "session" business was pre tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Keras you can plot your model using "plot_model", see documentation ( https://keras.io/utils/#plot_model ). If you want to use only Tensorflow you can still plot your model without training, see question ( [Is it possible to visualize a tensorflow graph without a training op?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391075/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-without-a-training-op) )